# Loops inside loops - I'm almost there but this code is just slightly off

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have two arrays of strings being passed in from another function. I'm trying to write a function to compare each element of the first array with each element of the second array, and print out whether the two elements are the same length.

x and y are the number of elements in a and b, respectively.

```
void translate(char **a, char **b,int x,int y)
{
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while(i < y)
    {
    while(j < x)
            {
            int q = strlen(a[j]);
            int w = strlen(b[i]);
            if(q == w)
                {
                printf("Entry %d of a matches entry %d of b\n",j,i);
                }
            else
                {
                printf("Entry %d of a does not match entry %d of b\n",j,i);
                }
        ++j;
        }
    ++i;
    }
return;
}
```

For the output, it's correctly comparing every entry of a with the first entry of b. That means that the outside loop isn't looping correctly and for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong. What am I doing wrong with the outside loop?

Comment: I'd start b moving the `int w = strlen(b[i]);` above the `while (j < x)` loop. No sense it recomputing that over and over again.

Comment: So `j` starts at 0 and gets bigger and never goes back to 0.

Comment: Please don't put tags in the question title. And for the sake of everything that's holy to you, please indent your code consistently and do not indent your curly braces!

Comment: Please consider using more descriptive variable names. It'll reduce headaches.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, your intent is probably to set `j` to zero outside the inner loop:

```
    while(j < x)
    {
         // ...
    }
    j = 0;
    ++i;
}
```

Otherwise, it will never re-enter the inner loop. Consider refactoring this into a for loop where your intent is clearer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < x; ++j)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```